# How to handle 0 entries in book crossing dataset

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I am working with book [crossing Data-set](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~cziegler/BX/) , It have a file which given user X's rating for book Y, but a lot of entries contains value 0 that means user X liked the book Y but did not give rating to it. I am using collaborative filtering hence these 0 entries are creating problems for me as if taken an 0 they decrease overall rating of the book.

I am new to Data science field can some one help how to handle this ?

What I can think of is replace 0 rating by user's average book rating but than again I don't any argument to support my Idea.

Comment: My suggestion is to increase all ratings by `1`. In that case, you will get a minimum rating for those _liked but not rated_ books, because that `0` will be converted to `1`.

Comment: @qmaruf for rated books rating is from 1-10 , even if I increase the 0 to 1 , still it will be biased compared to other books like for a user having ratings for books 7 , 8 , 8 , 7 . having a book with rating 1 implies he didnt liked the book but that is not the case , he just did'nt rate the book.

Comment: You're comparing a quantitative and qualitative rating so that's inherently tricky. If a user can like something but also rates them, you may need to test with cross validation to see which makes better recommendations (like = 1, like = average, like = 9). To learn more about recommendation system evaluation, this quora question is a great place to start: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-measure-and-evaluate-the-quality-of-recommendation-engines

Comment: This is not a question about programming - I'd recommend posting over on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISBN codes are very messy, contain a lot of incorrect ISBNs, and are not unified.

Here are just a few examples:

```
"User-ID";"ISBN";"Book-Rating"
"11676";" 9022906116";"7"
"11676";"\"0432534220\"";"6"
"11676";"\"2842053052\"";"7"
"11676";"0 7336 1053 6";"0"
"11676";"0=965044153";"7"
"11676";"0000000000";"9"
"11676";"00000000000";"8"
"146859";"01402.9182(PB";"7"
"158509";"0672=630155(P";"0"
"194500";"(THEWINDMILLP";"0"
```

So i would suggest to clean it up a little bit first:

```
df.ISBN = df.ISBN.str.replace(r'[^\w\d]+', '')
```

then calculate average ratings:

```
avg_ratings = df.groupby('ISBN')['Book-Rating'].mean().round().astype(np.int8)
```

and finally set average ratings to those books, having zero rating:

```
df.loc[df['Book-Rating'] == 0, 'Book-Rating'] = df.loc[df['Book-Rating'] == 0, 'ISBN'].map(avg_ratings)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).

Comment: we need to replace rating given by user X to book Y ( if it's 0 ) what according to your way rating for book Y will be then same for all users ( if it was 0 there )

Comment: we need to replace rating given by user X to book Y ( if it's 0 ) what according to your way rating for book Y will be then same for all users ( if it was 0 there )  , Isn't it wrong then ?

Comment: @rishabh, how do you want to calculate an average rating then?